# data.table aggregating over a subset of keys and joining with the subset

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table

I have a table, Y, which contains a subset of unique keys from a much larger table, X, which has many duplicate keys.  For each key in Y, I want to aggregate the same keys in X and add the aggregated variables to Y.  I've been playing around with data.table and I've come up with a way that works without having to make a copy, but I'm hoping there is a faster and less syntactically dizzying solution.  As more variables are added the syntax gets harder and harder to read and more helper references are made to table X when I really only care about them in table Y.

My question, just to clarify, is whether there is a more efficient and/or syntactically simpler way to do this operation.

My solution:

`Y[X[Y, b:= sum(a)], b := i.b, nomatch=0]`

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
X = data.table(id = sample.int(10,30, replace=TRUE), a = runif(30))
Y = data.table(id = seq(1,5))

setkey(X,id)
setkey(Y,id)

#head(X)

   #id         a
#1:  1 0.4112744
#2:  1 0.3162717
#3:  2 0.6470602
#4:  2 0.2447973
#5:  3 0.4820801
#6:  3 0.8273733

Y[X[Y, b := sum(a)], b := i.b, nomatch=0]

#head(Y)

#   id         b
#1:  1 0.7275461
#2:  2 0.8918575
#3:  3 3.0622883
#4:  4 2.9098465
#5:  5 0.7893562
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, we could use `data.table`'s by-without-by feature here...

```
## <= 1.9.2
X[Y, list(b=sum(a))]            ## implicit by-without-by

## 1.9.3
X[Y, list(b=sum(a)), by=.EACHI] ## explicit by
#    id         b
# 1:  1 0.7275461
# 2:  2 0.8918575
# 3:  3 3.0622883
# 4:  4 2.9098465
# 5:  5 0.7893562
```

In 1.9.3, `by-without-by` has now been changed to require *explicit* by`. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md) under 1.9.3 new features points (1) and (2), and the links from there.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
# set up a reproducible example
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
X = data.table(id = sample.int(10,30, replace=TRUE), a = runif(30))
Y = data.table(id = seq(1,5))
setkey(X,id)
setkey(Y,id)

# this statement does the work
result <- X[,list(b=sum(a)),keyby=id][Y]
result
# id         b
# 1:  1 0.7275461
# 2:  2 0.8918575
# 3:  3 3.0622883
# 4:  4 2.9098465
# 5:  5 0.7893562
```

This might be faster, as it subsets X first.

```
result.2 <- X[Y][,list(b=sum(a)),by=id]
identical(result, result.2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This creates a copy of all the rows for X[Y], so it's not quite what I'm looking for.